# Слияние файлов через bat

Tags: windows, консоль, bat

Господа, вопрос стоит вот таким образом:

> Обеспечить слияние n (значение n должно быть произвольным) файлов в
>   один с удалением исходных; файлы задаются параметрами командной
>   строки.

У меня получается вот такой код.

```
@echo off
echo:>CrLf.txt
copy /b 1.txt + CrLf.txt + 2.txt snr.txt
del /q 1.txt
del /q 2.txt
del /q CrLf.txt
```

Эта штука прекрасно работает. Производит объединение и удаление старых файлов. Но у меня никак не получается реализовать .bat файл так, чтобы n был произвольным и вводился с клавиатуры. Грубо говоря, как я понимаю, надо вбивать имена файлов вручную, потом, чтобы скрипт их всех открыл и поочередно объединил. Если у кого-то есть опыт работы с .bat подскажите что можно сделать.

Comment: Допустим ли вариант, когда первой строкой устанавливается cygwin, а потом в нем shell-скрипт запускается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно склеить командную строку. Например, так:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set cmd=copy /b 
    for %%x in (%*) do (
        if defined NotFirst set cmd=!cmd! + CrLf.txt + %%x
        if not defined NotFirst set cmd=!cmd!%%x
        set NotFirst=aa
    )   
    %cmd% out.txt
    for %%x in (%*) do (
        del /q %%x
    )   

endlocal
```

Здесь переменная cmd склеивается из команды `copy /b` и имен файлов, переданных в виде аргументов. Между именами добавляется оператор `+`.

Переменная `NotFirst` нужна для того, чтобы не прилеплять плюс первый раз (между командой и первым файлом)

Comment: Чет не выходит я в cmd пишу: D:\snt.bat D:\1.txt D:\2.txt D:\3.txt и ничего. Пишет скопировано файлов: 1. При этом новый файл не появляется на D диске. А нужно склеить именно контент файлов 1, 2 , 3.

Comment: @anj1817 все зависит от того, куда должен попасть склеенный файл. Сейчас я дописал имя прямо в батник - предпоследняя строка

Comment: По идее, он должен лежать в той-же деректории, что и те сам батник.

Comment: @anj1817 имя-то откуда брать?

Comment: Имя выходного файла можно задать в программе, а можно и ввести в консоли. Мне кажется это не принципиально.

Comment: @anj1817 тогда я это уже сделал - дописал out.txt в предпоследнюю строчку

Comment: Не работает. Пишет, что скопировано, но нет. файл out.txt не создается. Старые файлы не удаляются.
http://cs627219.vk.me/v627219070/18ec7/Dp86HhipF8A.jpg

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29335/discussion-between-gbg-and-anj1817).

Answer (score 2):

Не надо ему клеить командные строки. Вот так весь его код будет выглядеть:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 
echo:>CrLf.txt 
for %%a in (%*) do ( 
   copy /b snr.txt + %%a + CrLf.txt snr.txt 
   del /q %%a 
) 
del /q CrLf.txt
```

Comment: В задании русским по белому написано - Файлы задаются параметрами командной строки. А у вас что?

Comment: Чет я все равно не понял, как оно работает. Точнее  вообще не работает!

Comment: D:\snt.bat D:\1.txt D:\2.txt D:\3.txt - в результате сработки скрипта ничего не происходит. Новый файл не создается. В старых все теже записи.

Comment: Не понял, что для Вашего нужно snt.bat 3???